# Adding form inputs in form dynamically

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have started working through a guide on adding for elements dynamically, via button within your form.

The guide was here [Adding Form Elements](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/)

Now, I can follow most of it (i have little jQuery experience) but in my instance, I wish to add file fields, but the naming convention is a bit different, and its that waht is stumping me.

In my case, my first input has the name `name="matrix_field[row_new_0][col_id_1]"` and it is the `row_new_0` that I need to increase. I'm not sure how I can get that to work, as the number is not at the end of the name. Hope that makes sense!

**Right a quick edit as per requests.**

Here's the markup for this. It's taken directly from the tutorial I linked to.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="matrix_field[row_order][]" value="row_new_0" />

    <div id="input1" class="clonedInput">
       <input type="file" name="matrix_field[row_new_0][col_id_1]" />
    </div>

    <div>
       <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
       <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and heres the Javascript, together with the suggestion from jramby, but I'm getting some weird results....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

                var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'matrix_field[row_new_' + newNum + '][col_id_1]');
                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

                if (newNum == 5)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

                $('#input' + num).remove();
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    </script>
```

This is adding the extra field, but seems to getting some weird markup, so I am guessing its conflicting with something else in my js.

Anyhow, here's it is a http://jsfiddle.net/DdrfA/

However this seems to skip row_new_1 as it goes from `row_new_0` straight to `row_new_2` and also the remove button doesn't seems to work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant JavaScript and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse out the `row_new_0` pretty easily.  This is based on the linked example:

```
var newElem = $("#input").clone().attr('name', function (_, name) {
   return name.replace('row_new_0', 'row_new_' + num);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mdhn2/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding this line :

```
newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
```

you just have to put this line :

```
newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'matrix_field[row_new_' + newNum + '][col_id_1]');
```

May help more if I can get more details... I think you can see the missing question detail in my answer if existing.